# How to use relative links in AngularJS when running in a subdirectory?

Tags: angularjs

I am having some trouble using relative links in AngularJS.  I am not using ng-href in this instance, because it doesn't seem necessary.

I know that when I use `$location.path()`, I should always prefix the link with a forward slash - so if I want to go to the howTo page, I would use `$location.path("/howTo")`

I want to add an anchor tag to get to the howTo page in a menu.  I am not sure how to accomplish this - `<a href="/howTo">How To</a>` doesn't work because it will look for howTo at the root of the web server (I am running my app in a subdirectory).

Should I be prefixing my links with `#/`?  While it seems to work, I thought there may be a better way.  In the `$routeProvider`, I can say things like `.when('/howTo',...`, and I was hoping to find some level of consistency if possible.

Comment: Anchor tags are evaluated by the browser - not by AngularJS. What you pass to `$routeProvider` will also work for `$location`, so there is consistency there. If you aren't using html5 mode, then you should be prefixing your links in anchor tags with `#/`.

Comment: You can also use the <base href="/test/"> tag in the head to set the root folder of your application.